# How to determine bounding rectangles of multiple elements?

Tags: algorithm, graphics, geometry, bounding-box

I would like to implement an algorithm which will find the bounding rectangles of contours (already determined by another algorithm). The only thing I have is a binarized image (as shown below). The basic idea would be to :

- take something like this - a preprocessed binarized image 
  [image]
- and produce something like this 
  [image]

Comment: Check out our sister site, [DSP.SE].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out connected component labeling: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling . You can either find connected components of white pixels or black pixels in this case (White is computationally easier since you have fewer white points in the image).

Comment: I knew there had to be a name for this, it just took me two days of searching to find it.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest a naive approach for a start:

In the image, do a 2D binary search for a middle point in the image (x,y).
From that point, perform a flood fill.

- if the bounds of the filled figure are not those of the image, then you found a closed figure, and therefore its bounding box.
- if it fills the whole image, then you hitted nothing, so divide the image in four cuadrants and do the same recursively. (You don't need to check for points that fall inside a previously found bounding box figure, cutting your search space in the process).

Comment: By 2D binary do you mean a kd-tree?

Comment: I mean dividing the space in 4 cuadrants as in a quadtree.

Comment: I think a kd-tree will work, too. But a quadtree is nice to have.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like OpenCV has some algorithms for finding the bounding box of a contour already implemented. So looking into how their function works might be a good way to start.
http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rects_circles/bounding_rects_circles.html

Comment: Ok, that's a good idea but I want to start form scratch. I cannot use OpenCV's implementation.

Comment: Is it possible in your implementation of the contour creation function to group each contour as a set of points? If you can do that then it becomes almost trivial to find the bounding box, since you just have to find the highest, lowest, left-most, and right-most point in each set.

Comment: I have got just a binarized image - that's all. I have to somehow sort out the bounding rectangles.

Comment: Well what you could do then is implement some contour tracing algorithm, like Moore-Neighbor or Radial Sweep, that would be fairly simple but allow you to group the white pixels once you found them. So essentially start going through the image until you find a white pixel. Set that as your starting pixel and apply the contour tracing algorithm. Once the algorithm has finished tracing use the set of pixels that it found to determine the bounding box. Then find the next white pixel that isn't in the set of previously found contours and start applying the algorithm again.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I will try to find some materials on the Internet. If you find something though, please post it in the comment.

Answer (score -1):

For each element:

```
They highest y - 1 is the top of the rectangle. 
The leftmost x - 1 is the left of the rectangle. 
The lowest y + 1 is the bottom of the rectangle. 
The rightmost x + 1 is the right of the rectangle.
```

Note by highest I mean closest to the top of the screen not the greatest value.

Comment: You misunderstood me a little: a have picture(matrix of 0s and 1s) and I want to find these rectangles - their coordinates.

Answer (score -1):

You can calculate a minimum spanning tree and remove the longest edges. Then you can calculate the k-means. Remove another long edge and calculate the k-means. Rinse and repeat until you have N=10. I believe this algorithm is named single-link k-means and the cluster are similar to voronoi diagrams:

"The single-link k-clustering algorithm ... is precisely Kruskal's algorithm ... equivalent to finding an MST and deleting the k-1 most expensive edges."

See for example here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/visualization-software-for-clustering

Then for each cluster you apply this rule:

```
They highest y - 1 is the top of the rectangle. 
The leftmost x - 1 is the left of the rectangle. 
The lowest y + 1 is the bottom of the rectangle. 
The rightmost x + 1 is the right of the rectangle.
```

Note by highest I mean closest to the top of the screen not the greatest value.